# Is changing Session Id the best solution for Session Fixation and why does changing Session ID raises Session_End event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, session-cookies

During security vulnerability test, our client requested the application to change session ID specifically ASP.NET_SessionID cookie value after users successfully log into the system. This could probably solve **session fixation** how ever session_end event will be raised when Session Id got changed and that causes to restart the session(the system) which will again redirects to login page. Is there any way to change session ID without causing all this?

Please suggest any work around.

Comment: Why don't you export the session to OutProc storage like Distributed cache provider or StateServer or SQL Server, change the Id and restore the session afterward and associate the session with new ID.This way the ID will be changed and the user will remain logged in.

Comment: @KevinRyan: that is what I was trying to do first on local machine(inProc storage). However, Changing Session Id is causing session_end event to be raised.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  When people talk about changing the session Id to prevent session fixation, they usually have in mind vulnerabilities that happen in Java frameworks where knowing the sessionId is enough to take over a session.

However, ASP.NET is a different beast.  ASP.NET has two things needed to take over a session: the sessionId and the ASPXAUTH cookie.  If you Google around, you will find unjustified claims that there are still session fixation possibilities, but I am not convinced because nobody seems to be demonstrating how to exploit them.  The closest I found to evidence that it can be exploited is [this blog](http://blog.securityps.com/2013/06/session-fixation-forms-authentication.html), which is insightful to say the least.  The blog does identify a poor implementation in ASP.NET -- the framework not checking that the sessionId and the ASPXAUTH are tied to the same user (unless the developer explicitly adds this check).  But is it exploitable?  I can think of cases where it might be exploitable if the developer had done something wrong that allows worse exploits than session fixation, but otherwise, I doubt it.

Definitely a topic that needs more research.  I realise my answer is coming too late for your needs, but thought I'd follow up anyway.  Bottom line: Changing the sessionId after login does not seem to provide any extra protection.  If your pentesters think otherwise, I'd invite them to explain it to me.